# Doobie. Set connection timeout

Tags: scala, doobie

How to set connection timeout using `Doobie`?

For now, I am creating a new `hikari transactor`, and then configuring it:

```
def buildTransactor(driver: String, uri: String, 
                    user: String, pwd: String, 
                    timeout: Long) = for {
  ce <- ExecutionContexts.fixedThreadPool[Task](10)
  te <- ExecutionContexts.cachedThreadPool[Task]
  xa <- HikariTransactor.newHikariTransactor[Task](
    driver, uri, user, pwd, ce, te)
  _ <- configure(xa, timeout)   // Configure transactor
} yield xa


def configure(xa: HikariTransactor[Task], timeout: Long) = Resource.liftF(
  xa.configure(ds => Task(ds.setConnectionTimeout(timeout)))
)
```

I am not sure it is ok. Docs says nothing.